# Riak: Create index on key via Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala, indexing, riak

I have a bucket on riak in which I store simple `Timestamp -> String` values in this way:

```
val riakClient = RiakFactory.newClient(myHttpClusterConfig)
val myBucket = riakClient.fetchBucket(name).execute
myBucket.store(timestamp.toString, value).withoutFetch().w(1).execute
```

What I need to do now is to add an index on the keys. I tried defining a Java POJO in this way:

```
public class MyWrapper {
    @RiakIndex(name="timestamp_index")
    @RiakKey
    public String timestamp;
    public String value;

    public MyWrapper(String timestamp, String value) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

and then running

```
myBucket.store(new MyWrapper(timestamp.toString, value)).withoutFetch().w(1).execute
```

The problem of this approach is that in riak the actual value is stored as a json object:

```
{"value":"myvalue"}
```

while I would simply need to store the `myvalue` string. Is there any way to achieve this? I can't see any `index(name)` method when executing `store`, and I can't see any annotations like `@RiakKey` but for values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a RiakObject using a RiakObjectBuilder, and then add the index on that:

```
val obj = RiakObjectBuilder.newBuilder(bucketName, myKey)
      .withValue(myValue)
      .addIndex("timestamp_index", timestamp)
      .build
myBucket.store(obj).execute
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are trying to do, you want the key/value pair `"1403909549"`/`"Some Value"` to be indexed by `timestamp_index="1403909549"` so that you can query specific times or ranges of times.

If that is the case, you do not need to explicitly add an index, you can query the implicit index `$KEY` in the same manner you would any other index.

Since all keys that Riak stores in LevelDB are indexed implicitly, I don't think a method was exposed to index them again explicitly.

Comment: Hey Joe, thank you for your answer, I didn't know of the implicit `$KEY` index, +1 for that. Your solution would work if I had to store only these `Timestamp -> String` values in `myBucket`, but unfortunately I have other keys with a different semantics that I don't want to keep into consideration when querying on `timestamp_index`